# Excel VBA scraping web data, entering input into AJAX autocomplete does not trigger list

Tags: vba, excel

First time trying this.

I have the following `HTML` in a web page and I am using `Excel` and `VBA` to scrape data based on user addresses in my `excel` file. The issue I am having is the `combobox` does not accept any input but it has to be a selection from its drop down list.

I can select the input field and add my entry, but the drop list does not appear. The site is using an `autocomplete` where the list is built by an `AJAX` call once it detects an input.

How do I trigger the drop list in the combobox and select the correct entry from it to match the input from my range (if it exists)? The code below is one of my various attempts.

The url is `http://play.afl/club-finder/?` and I am trying to enter a suburb name in the last field next to the `GO` button. Try, for example, `Parramatta`

An observation is that for the `combobox` element:

```
<input role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" value="Parramatta, NSW" autocomplete="off">
```

If I type the value manually into the field, inspect shows the `value=` changing as I type it. When the `vba` changes this value, it does not get changed in inspect.

Thank you

```
<div class="program-filters">
   <span>Search for&nbsp;</span>
   <a>
      any gender&nbsp;<img src="/site/images/svg/DownArrow.svg" alt="Down Arrow" class="down-arrow-icon">
   </a>
   <span class="xs-hide">,</span>
   <br class="sm-hide md-hide lg-hide">
   <a>
      all ages&nbsp;<img src="/site/image/svg/DownArrow.svg" alt="Down Arrow" class="down-arrow-icon">
   </a>
   to
   <a>
      play&nbsp;<img src="/site/images/svg/DownArrow.svg" alt="Down Arrow" class="down-arrow-icon">
   </a>
   <br class="sm-hide md-hide lg-hide">&nbsp;near&nbsp;
   <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <input role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" value="SEARCH VALUE HERE">
   </div>
   <a class="in-map-btn btn btn-primary btn-go btn-mobile-fixed">GO</a>
</div>
```

My macro so far is:

```
Sub get_data()

Const myURL As String = "http://play.afl/club-finder/?"

Dim c As Range

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate myURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

For Each c In Range("MY_SEARCH")

    Set searchBar = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("program-filters")(0)

    Set myInput = searchBar.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(0)

    myInput.Focus
    myInput.Value = c.Value
    myInput.FireEvent ("onchange")

    Set myAutoComplete = searchBar.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete")(0)

    If Not myAutoComplete Is Nothing Then

       'FIND IN LIST AND SELECT HERE

        searchBar.getElementsByClassName("in-map-btn btn btn-primary btn-go btn-mobile-fixed")(0).Click

        Do While appIE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'COLLECT DATA HERE

    End If

Next

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Tried executing `jQuery` from `vba` to trigger the `AJAX`, with no errors but not working:

```
appIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "jQuery('.program-filters input').trigger('change')"
```

Using the suggestion below still not working though no errors:

```
jq = "jQuery('.program-filters input').val('" & c.Value & "').trigger('change')"
appIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript jq
```

Comment: it helps if you set the focus to the control you are manipulating, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/02/vba-ie-createevent-and-dispatchevent-to.html#focusTip

Comment: Crawling/Scraping this site is forbidden under the T&C's.

Answer (score 0):

You probably both have to fill in a value in the input field (combobox) AND trigger the change event for this to work. Try this:

```
appIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "jQuery('.program-filters input').val('yourvalue').trigger('change')"
```

Comment: Hi @Miqi180 thanks for the suggestion. See my update above, it did not work though no errors.

Comment: On this particular site you cannot just copy-paste your search term into the input field. This doesn't trigger the AJAX for the dropdown list and is what you've been doing programmatically so far, so my suggestion is that you analyze the javascript event handlers on the site. Chrome developer tools --> Sources tab --> Event listener breakpoints. This should tell you exactly which event triggers the AJAX and subsequent display of the dropdown list.